# can't use squid any more because /var/cache/squid got deleted

Tags: squid

I have manually deleted the file /var/cache/squid. Now I get this error:

```
stat: cannot stat ‘/var/cache/squid’: No such file or directory
```

To use squid again, what should I do? I'm using Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: `squid` should create the directory if not there..try `service squid3 restart`

Comment: Shutdown squid service, and then run squid directly with the -z flag.  Then 'squid -k shutdown' and then restart it using service.

Comment: chown: invalid user: ‘squid:squid’
dpkg: error processing package squid3 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 squid3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Is that the correct user:group for squid?

Comment: Looks like the directory is not the only thing you deleted.

Comment: @Brian I don't know exactly  about the user :group

Comment: @muru I have only deleted the directory , how could I know about the things which are missing ?